# How to give path properly in C#

Tags: c#

I have a folder in my project named Export, I save files to that folder using this code :

```
document.Save(@"D:\workspace\folder1\Solution.Application.DataExporter\Export\mydocument.pdf");
```

But when others use this code, they complain that they don't have that path. How can I give path to my code so that it works everywhere? Thanks.

Comment: Why not prompt the user to specify a path, then they can export it wherever they want.

Comment: You can use Environment.SpecialFolder to find/access/create folders where you have permissions. Also, the C: with no backslah as in c:MyFile.txt will use your project folder. You will have permissions in appdata https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx Environment.SpecialFolder is likely the way to go for distribution, because you can virtually guarantee that every user will have one.

Comment: @dman2306 Because requirements are like that.

Comment: @Jason if the requirements are to save a file to a folder that doesn't exist, it sounds like you need someone to revise the requirements... What if I don't even have a D drive on my computer? Is there a requirement that a D drive must exist as well?

Comment: @Jason I seriously doubt that there is a requirement to hardcode a path. Prompt the user, either each time or allow him to set the folder in a settings dialog. User files should *always* be stored in `My Documents` by the way. Ask the user, *don't* try to find some random folder

Comment: @jason - Then what are the requirements?

Comment: @Vilx- The requirement is, there is an Export folder in the project, and I need to save files to that folder. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: @jason - OK, so what do the requirements say about the location of "the project"? How do you know in which folder "the project" is?

Comment: @Vilx- I thought there is a special path for project as well, like mydocuments. Am I right?

Comment: @jason - That depends on what you mean by "a project". Windows itself doesn't have such a concept, but there are various other things that might suit you. If "a project" is mentioned in your requirements, then I would expect it to clarify, what it is.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:** Use the `Environment.SpecialFolder` to get the physical location of a special folder. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for an overview of possible special folders.

For example, if you want to put the document in 'my documents' folder, then `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` would give you the location to the my documents folder on the current machine.

Code:

```
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

This way you are sure you always have the correct and existing location. If needed, you can always first create an export folder into this special folder with `Directory.CreateDirectory()`, if it does not exist yet.

**Option 2:** Of course, you can always ask for a location to the user if you don't want to use a predefined one, by using the [SaveFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) class, for example.

Comment: I read the ?? as the OP is looking for *A* folder, not *the* folder. Using d:\ is a bad idea from the start as not everyone even has a d";\

Comment: @sstan I just gave two options, it's not sure the location HAS to be that. it just has to work everywhere.

Comment: My Documents is a good place to store user documents. AppData is a good place to store application data, settings, lookup values etc. A workspace sounds more like user documents, although the end user should be able to specify a different location

Comment: @sstan that's a non-existent folder. The OP is trying to save in a disk or folder that doesn't exist. `MyDocuments` is the best option to start with user generated files, workspaces, project folders, etc. If I remember correctly, it's also the default location for `SaveFileDialog`

Comment: @sstan we do actually, it's in the question. It's very unclear, and the OP is trying to avoid asking the user. This answer though is the best starting point

Comment: @Panagiotis: Yes, I see your point. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create the folder 'Export' in MyDocuments, and then save the file to that directory. As many others have pointed out. You need to save to a directory, that the executing user has access rights to.

```
string documentFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), @"Export");

if (!Directory.Exists(documentFolder))
{
   Directory.CreateDirectory(documentFolder);
}

document.Save(Path.Combine(documentFolder, "mydocument.pdf"));
```